# I want to make a todo list but I am stuck at the start, where am I going wrong in this code?

Tags: javascript, button

I want to add `li` to the `ul` element with the value entered by user in the input area.
This is the error I am getting in console:

```
[Error] TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName("list-group").appendChild is not a function. (In 'document.getElementsByClassName("list-group").appendChild("li")', 'document.getElementsByClassName("list-group").appendChild' is undefined)
    additem (script.js:7)
```

```js
//this is my javascript code-->

    function additem() {
    var task = document.getElementsByClassName("input-group-text").value;
    
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("list-group-item");
    li = "task";
    document.getElementsByClassName("list-group").appendChild("li");
    }
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",additem);
```

```html
 //<--!this is my html code-->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>LearnCodeOnline</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    </head>
    <body class="bg-dark">
    <div class="container bg-warning p-4">
      <h1 class="text-center">LearnCodeOnline</h1>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-text">todo</span>
        <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
      </div>
      
      <button id="button" class="float-right">Add</button>
      
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
        </ul>
      
      <!-- <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-success btn-lg mt-4 mx-auto d-block sort-btn"
      >
        Sort courses
      </button> -->
       </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `getElemetsByClassName` returns a Nodelist and you should iterate over it rather than just appending the li to it. Try logging `getElementsByClassName("list-group")` and you will see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:-

```
function additem() {
    var task = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].value;
    
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("list-group-item");
    li.innerText = task;
    document.getElementsByClassName("list-group")[0].appendChild(li);
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",additem);
```

- Instead of doing `.appendChild("li")`, we'll give it an element and not string as it takes the element and not string
- `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array so we will take the item at 0th index of the array in both the functions where it is there
- also instead of setting `li = "task"` like this, we'll have to set its text by `li.innerText = task`

Comment: does getElementsByClassName() always returns an array?

Comment: Yes, if you want to select only one element, give `id` to the element and  do `getElementById('myId')`

Comment: can u tell me the best source to learn javascript?

Comment: @HimanshuSharma If you want to learn from Youtube, [CodeWithHarry](https://www.youtube.com/codewithharry) is a good option, [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.youtube.com/freecodecamp) is also a nice option. You can also see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).